# IIS URL rewriting has trouble with subcalls

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have two virtual machines. The first one (VM1) is running a web application with an URL like this:

> VM1/servicedesk/customer/user/login

The second (VM2) should now redirect to this address **without** changing the URL and also doesn't allow to redirect to the root / since that is a different web-application. This works relatively easily with this rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="rewriteAll" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="http://VM1/servicedesk/customer/user/login" />
</rule>
```

It just basically rewrites everything from VM2 to the specific VM1 URL.
The problem I'm facing is that this web-application has many Ajax calls to other addresses on the same VM1. 
For example VM1/rest/... or VM1/s/.... I really tried to find each exceptional call and create a rule **before** this default Rewrite. But since some of them are nested and could be changed this isn't a good approach. So what i need is basically a rewrite without changing the URL what doesn't break the application that does a lot of nested calls.

Comment: 1) locate all the possible URL patterns. 2) Analyze and decide which are the rules you have to write. Since you don't list enough information above, you have to dig out the answer by yourself.

Comment: That answers my question in principle already. Yes I can of course create rules for all exceptions and addresses that are called from this address, but I thought there might be a trick how to do this with 1-2 rules. What informations are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that i can use the following rule (`redirectRest`) before the existing `rewriteAll` rule to redirect subcalls (VM1/rest/..).

```
<rule name="redirectRest" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="/.*" />
 <action type="Redirect" url="http://VM1/{R:0}" />
</rule>
<rule name="rewriteAll" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url=".*" />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="http://VM1/servicedesk/customer/user/login" />
</rule>
```

So basically when I call VM1 the second rule applies and I get rewritten to the web-app. The application hosted there will call e.g. VM1/rest what triggers the first rule and redirect the Ajax calls to the root. But I've found out that Ajax calls are not following a redirect like 301.

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.